# Transact SQL - Is it possible to SUM () without GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, grouping

I have the following code (see below).
Is it possible to re-write it, in the way - to avoid using

**Group By** statement

Please see below:

```
DECLARE @MonthBOP date = '07-01-2017'
DECLARE @MonthEOP date = '02-28-2018'
DECLARE @GLRegionsWHID int = -1

SELECT
 e.[GLRegion]
,e.[GLRegionWHID]
,e.[GLProgram]
,e.[GLProgramWHID] 
,e.[DOLStatus] 
,e.[DOLStatusWHID]
,e.[TerminationType]
,e.[TerminationReason]

 ,SUM(IIF((e.[DateHired] <= @MonthBOP) AND (e.[DateTerminated] >= @MonthBOP), 1, 0)) AS [CountEmployeesBOP]
,SUM(IIF((e.[DateHired] <= @MonthEOP) AND (e.[DateTerminated] >= @MonthEOP), 1, 0)) AS [CountEmployeesEOP]
,SUM(IIF(e.[DateTerminated] BETWEEN @MonthBOP AND @MonthEOP, 1, 0)) AS [CountTerminations]

FROM 
    [Reports].[vPaycomEmployee] e

WHERE
    ((e.[DateHired] <= @MonthEOP) OR (e.[DateTerminated] > @MonthBOP)) 
AND ((e.[GLRegionWHID] IN (@GLRegionsWHID)) OR (-1 IN (@GLRegionsWHID)))


GROUP BY
 e.[GLRegion]
,e.[GLRegionWHID]
,e.[GLProgram]
,e.[GLProgramWHID] 
,e.[DOLStatus] 
,e.[DOLStatusWHID]
,e.[TerminationType]
,e.[TerminationReason]

HAVING
(SUM(IIF((e.[DateHired] <= @MonthBOP) AND (e.[DateTerminated] >= @MonthBOP), 
     1, 0)) > 0)
```

I need to avoid Group By because it affects the resulting calculations

Comment: You would have to bracket it I guess: { SELECT CandidateID, ( SELECT SUM(candidateID) FROM tblCandidate) FROM tblCandidate }  this works but it will of course be quite a bit slower if this is a big database.

Comment: What is group by breaking?  We have no idea what it is that you need to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple different ways: you could use subqueries...

This is very loose, as I'm not entirely sure what you mean by, "I need to avoid Group By because it affects the resulting calculations" (affects them how? What results are you hoping for?), but something like the following might work (this example assumes you just want to list every record but count the records by GLRegion, and also match the rest of your WHERE criteria):

```
DECLARE @MonthBOP date = '07-01-2017'
DECLARE @MonthEOP date = '02-28-2018'
DECLARE @GLRegionsWHID int = -1

SELECT
     e.[GLRegion]
    ,e.[GLRegionWHID]
    ,e.[GLProgram]
    ,e.[GLProgramWHID] 
    ,e.[DOLStatus] 
    ,e.[DOLStatusWHID]
    ,e.[TerminationType]
    ,e.[TerminationReason]
    ,(SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM [Reports].[vPaycomEmployee] e1 
        WHERE (e1.[DateHired] <= @MonthBOP) 
            AND (e1.[DateTerminated] >= @MonthBOP) 
            AND (e1.[GLRegion] = e.[GLRegion])
            AND ((e1.[GLRegionWHID] IN (@GLRegionsWHID)) OR (-1 IN (@GLRegionsWHID)))
        ) AS [CountEmployeesBOP]
    ,(SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM [Reports].[vPaycomEmployee] e1 
        WHERE (e1.[DateHired] <= @MonthEOP) 
            AND (e1.[DateTerminated] >= @MonthEOP) 
            AND (e1.[GLRegion] = e.[GLRegion])
            AND ((e1.[GLRegionWHID] IN (@GLRegionsWHID)) OR (-1 IN (@GLRegionsWHID)))
        ) AS [CountEmployeesEOP]
    ,(SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM [Reports].[vPaycomEmployee] e1 
        WHERE (e1.[DateTerminated] BETWEEN @MonthBOP AND @MonthEOP) 
            AND (e1.[GLRegion] = e.[GLRegion])
            AND ((e1.[GLRegionWHID] IN (@GLRegionsWHID)) OR (-1 IN (@GLRegionsWHID)))
        ) AS [CountTerminations]
FROM [Reports].[vPaycomEmployee] e
WHERE
    ((e.[DateHired] <= @MonthEOP) OR (e.[DateTerminated] > @MonthBOP)) 
    AND ((e.[GLRegionWHID] IN (@GLRegionsWHID)) OR (-1 IN (@GLRegionsWHID)))
    AND (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM [Reports].[vPaycomEmployee] e1 
        WHERE (e1.[DateHired] <= @MonthBOP) 
            AND (e1.[DateTerminated] >= @MonthBOP)
        ) > 0
```

(Note that I replaced the SUMs with COUNTs, since that does seem to be what you're going for, and it's simpler that way.)